# I want to give dynamic colum name like that in Oracle is it possible?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some categories having title and values. The title and values are dynamic.

I want to query them like this:

```
Select GET_CATEGORY_VALUE(ID) As GET_CATEGORY_TITLE(ID) From DUAL;
```

But an error occurs:

> FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: You have to use dynamic SQL (`execute immediate`) to dynamically change column names.

Comment: Only with dynamic SQL, and even then there will be limits - e.g. on alias length. Anything using the results would need to know the names though, so it is probably only useful (if at all) for final display - and then your presentation/reporting layer can take care of it?